# D3 tooltip: Cannot read property 'getBoundingClientRect' of null

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Here's my Plunker, so you can follow along:
http://plnkr.co/edit/BsLMhbldIYvZEVOu23aM?p=preview

I thought I was close to getting a tooltip to work, but I encountered the following error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getBoundingClientRect' of null
```

The problematic code, it seems, is:

```
      var toolW = d3.select('.tooltip').node().getBoundingClientRect().width;

          if(d3.event.pageX > (width - toolW)) {
            tt.style('left', d3.event.pageX - toolW - 30 + 'px')
          } else {
            tt.style('left', d3.event.pageX + 30 + 'px')
          }
        });
```

The problematic code above works perfectly in its original block: http://bl.ocks.org/sdbernard/2e44bd82c9d048b88451/2b31b98b8f6acb8d7c6026b5eec801e2f1f61ab2

I've adapted that block into this (semi-working) Plunker (same as above), but my code throws the error:
http://plnkr.co/edit/BsLMhbldIYvZEVOu23aM?p=preview

I'm lost. How do I fix this, so that the tooltip appears?

Comment: Your selection is of a DOM element with the class "tooltip", but your tooltip div has an id of "tooltip". Because of this `d3.select(".tooltip").node()` is null. It will work if you change your div from having `id="tooltip"` to having  `class="tooltip"` : http://plnkr.co/edit/UMhCPna6BIRABkeqDmOY?p=preview , or alternatively set your selector to "#tooltip"

Comment: Voting to close this as *"simple typographical error"*.

Comment: [Andrew Reid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47103259/d3-tooltip-cannot-read-property-getboundingclientrect-of-null?noredirect=1#comment81157746_47103259) found my error: I needed to change "id" to "class"